# Computer does not print, accept remote-connections nor open SMB folders until restart

Tags: windows, authentication, time-synchronization

I encountered a Windows 10 which seems to have problems with authentication. The computer does not accept remote connections, does not open smb-folders or print a file (no error shown, when the pc tries to print). Only when I restart the machine, the problems disappear for a while (sometimes 30min, sometimes a day). I thought it might be a time-problem, but I checked the time configuration. Updating the machine does not solve the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sfc /scannow first, have a look at the event logs for anything strange. Also worthwhile doing a malware scan with e.g. Malwarebytes.